# vsftpd not allowing uploads. 550 response

Tags: centos, ftp, vsftpd

I've set vsftpd up on a centos box. I keep trying to upload files but I keep getting "550 Failed to change directory" and "550 Could not get file size."

Here's my vsftpd.conf

```
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Beware - allowed by default if you comment this out).
anonymous_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# The target log file can be vsftpd_log_file or xferlog_file.
# This depends on setting xferlog_std_format parameter
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# The name of log file when xferlog_enable=YES and xferlog_std_format=YES
# WARNING - changing this filename affects /etc/logrotate.d/vsftpd.log
#xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
#
# Switches between logging into vsftpd_log_file and xferlog_file files.
# NO writes to vsftpd_log_file, YES to xferlog_file
xferlog_std_format=NO
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd/banned_emails
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# When "listen" directive is enabled, vsftpd runs in standalone mode and
# listens on IPv4 sockets. This directive cannot be used in conjunction
# with the listen_ipv6 directive.
listen=YES

# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. To listen on IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets, you must run two copies of vsftpd whith two configuration files.
# Make sure, that one of the listen options is commented !!
#listen_ipv6=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
banner_file=/etc/vsftpd/issue
local_root=/var/www
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=ftpusr
ftp_username=nobody
```

Comment: Are you logging in, or using anonymous?  Is selinux enabled ( you can find out by running getsebool)

Comment: If by logging in, you mean that I'm putting my un and pw into my ftp client... selinux is not enabled. As I'm sure you can tell, server administration is definitely not my forte.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that could cause a 550 error; a couple of fixes you could try:

- If you are logging in as an *anonymous* user try setting the directive

  anon_world_readable_only=NO

This directive, by default, is set to YES, and means that anonymous users can only download files which are world-readable on the file system; if your files are not world readable, or are being created without world read privileges, anonymous users will not be able to access them.

- If you are logging in as an *anonymous* user, you also need the directive

  anon_root={some_dir}

This is the directory that vsftpd will change to after an anonymous login

- If you are logging in as a different user, ensure that the user has read and write permissions on the */var/www* directory (your local_root)

<sub>(Note: I haven't used vsftpd in some time, so my memory of these directives may be a little fuzzy; I *think* they are right.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As a previous commenter stated I would seriously look to see if selinux is enabled. On centos you can see in /etc/sysconfig/selinux.

Answer (score 0):

```
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=ftpusr
```

Given you are enabling guest_enable, authenticated users such as yourself are being run as the ftpusr account on the server.  You can either chown -R ftpusr /var/www or comment out guest_enable, and have /var/www owned by your user ( or have appropriate permissions via group, or other, or using faclset ).